# How to compare dataframe column texts according to a rule?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a project for university in which I want to use the associations beetween two dataframes.

```
      import pandas as pd
      from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
      from fuzzywuzzy import process

      dataframe_one = pd.DataFrame({'city_name': ['LISBOA', 'LISBOA', 'RIO DE JANEIRO', 
                                                  'BARCELONA', 'PARIS'],                   
                                    'address_name':['ESPLANADA DOM CARLOS',
                                                    'AVENIDA BRASILIA',
                                                    'PARQUE NACIONAL DA TIJUCA',
                                                    'C D ARISTIDES MAILLOL',
                                                    'CHAMP DE MARS 5 AV ANATOLE']})

      dataframe_two = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['RIO DE JANEIRO', 'RIO DE JANEIRO', 'LISBOA'],                   
                                    'population': [6748, 6748, 504],
                                    'address':['PQ NACIONAL TIJUCA', 'URCA', 
                                               'ESPLANADAA DOM CARLO']})
```

What I want to do is compare the two dataframes. So if the city is the same, then analyze the similarity between the address columns. If the address similarity value is greater than a THRESHOLD, then I assign values ​​in the new columns. I did the following:

```
      THRESHOLD = 80

      dataframe_two['NewColumn1'] = None
      dataframe_two['NewColumn2'] = 0

      for i in range(0, len(dataframe_one)):
          for j in range(0, len(dataframe_two)):
    
              if(dataframe_one['city_name'].iloc[i] == dataframe_two['city'].iloc[j]):
        
                  adress1 = dataframe_one['address_name'].iloc[i]
                  adress2 = dataframe_two['address'].iloc[j]            
                  value_fuzzy = fuzz.ratio(adress1, adress2)
        
                  if(value_fuzzy > THRESHOLD):
                      dataframe_two['NewColumn1'].loc[j] = \
                          dataframe_one['address_name'].iloc[i]
                      dataframe_two['NewColumn2'].loc[j] = value_fuzzyvalue_fuzzy
```

The implementation outputs to the second dataframe as expected, but I would like to replace it with more efficient code.

Output:

```
      city       population    address                NewColumn1                NewColumn2
RIO DE JANEIRO     6748       PQ NACIONAL TIJUCA    PARQUE NACIONAL DA TIJUCA      84
RIO DE JANEIRO     6748       URCA                  None                            0
LISBOA              504       ESPLANADAA DOM CARLO  ESPLANADA DOM CARLOS            95
```

Question 2 - Now the dataframe_one has a new column, called 'number'. As below:

```
       dataframe_one = pd.DataFrame({'number': [101, 102, 103, 104, 
                                                105],
                                     'city_name': ['LISBOA', 
                                                   'LISBOA', 
                                                   'RIO DE JANEIRO', 
                                                   'BARCELONA', 
                                                   'PARIS'],                   
                                 'address_name':['ESPLANADA DOM CARLOS',
                                                 'AVENIDA BRASILIA',
                                           'PARQUE NACIONAL DA TIJUCA',
                                          'C D ARISTIDES MAILLOL',
                                     'CHAMP DE MARS 5 AV                                               
                                      ANATOLE']})
```

I would like to add the new 'number' column in the result dataframe. So I tried to do:

```
      l = []
      TRESHOLD = 80

      # ITERATE OVER THE SECOND DATAFRAME
      for _ ,row in dataframe_two.iterrows():
           # CREATE NEW ROW FOR THE RESULT
           d = {**row, 'NewColumn1':None, 'NewColumn2':None, 
                'NewColumn3':None}

          # FIND MATCHES
          d1_subset = dataframe_one.loc[dataframe_one['city_name'] == 
                      row['city']]

          # ITERATE OVER THE MATCHES    
          if d1_subset.shape[0] > 0:
              best_adress = None
              best_score = 0
              # Create new variable
              best_number = 0
              adresses = d1_subset['address_name'].tolist()
              best_number = d1_subset['number'].tolist()
    
              # FIND BEST MATCH
              for adress in adresses:
                  value_fuzzy = fuzz.ratio(adress, row['address'])
        
                  if value_fuzzy > best_score:
                      best_adress = adress
                      best_score = value_fuzzy              

              # IF BEST SCORE IS ABOVE THRESHOLD
              if best_score > TRESHOLD:            
                  d['NewColumn1'] = best_adress
                  d['NewColumn2'] = best_score
                  # New column
                 d['NewColumn3'] = best_number
        
          l.append(d)

      # CREATE DATAFRAME FROM THE RESULT
      df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

The final dataframe continues to give the expected response in the columns: city, population, address, NewColumn1 and NewColumn2. However, the NewColumn3 column returns:

```
      NewColumn3
       [103]
       None
     [101, 102]
```

I would like the NewColumn3 column to return:

```
      NewColumn3
       103
       None
       101
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another implementation that finds the best match in you initial dataframe.

```
l = []
TRESHOLD = 80
# ITERATE OVER THE SECOND DATAFRAME
for _ ,row in dataframe_two.iterrows():
    # CREATE NEW ROW FOR THE RESULT
    d = {**row, 'NewColumn1':None, 'NewColumn2':None, 'NewColumn3':None}

    # FIND MATCHES
    d1_subset = dataframe_one.loc[dataframe_one['city_name'] == row['city']]

    # ITERATE OVER THE MATCHES    
    if d1_subset.shape[0] > 0:
        best_adress, best_number = None, None
        best_score = 0
        adresses = d1_subset['address_name'].tolist()
        numbers = d1_subset['number'].tolist()
        # FIND BEST MATCH
        for adress,number in zip(adresses,numbers):
            value_fuzzy = fuzz.ratio(adress, row['address'])
            if value_fuzzy > best_score:
                best_adress = adress
                best_score = value_fuzzy
                best_number = number
        # IF BEST SCORE IS ABOVE THRESHOLD
        if best_score > TRESHOLD:            
            d['NewColumn1'] = best_adress
            d['NewColumn2'] = best_score
            d['NewColumn3'] = best_number

    l.append(d)

# CREATE DATAFRAME FROM THE RESULT
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Comment: In place of d1, would the correct one be dataframe_one?
(On the line "# FIND MATCHES
    d1_subset = dataframe_one.loc[d1['city_name'] == row['city']]")

Comment: Sry, that was a typo. I fixed it in the answer

Comment: The code worked perfectly! I need to add a new column in the response dataframe. This time the dataframe_one has an identifier column, called 'number'. I would like this column to also be stored in the final dataframe (according to the row with the highest fuzzy result). I edited the new scenario in the question.

Comment: I've changed the code, so that it now also does what you ask in Question2

Comment: worked perfectly.